# pandas how to use apply function to check if 2 values exist

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a small script in which I am using the pandas apply a function to find out if two values exist in two different columns exist. 
In this instance, if the data frame contains a value of 2005 within the year column and value of 7 within the month column, return a value called "entry for year month exist" into a new column called "check column". But I am getting a whole load of errors and can't quite figure it out. Any ideas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2005,2006,2007,2005,2008], 'month': [7,9,12,7,9]})

def check(y,m):
  if y in df['year'] and m in df['month']:
    return ('entry for year month exist')

df['check column'] = df[['year','month']].apply(check, 2005,7, axis = 1)
print(df)
```

The error I am getting is `apply() got multiple values for argument 'axis'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with test by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for better performance:

```
df['check column'] = np.where(df['year'].eq(2005) & df['month'].eq(7), 
                              'entry for year month exist', 
                              'not exist')

print(df)  
   year  month                check column
0  2005      7  entry for year month exist
1  2006      9                   not exist
2  2007     12                   not exist
3  2005      7  entry for year month exist
4  2008      9                   not exist
```

Apply is possible, but slow, because loops under the hood, so not recommended:

```
def check(x, y,m):
  if  x['year'] == y and x['month'] == m:
    return 'entry for year month exist'
  else:
      return 'not exist'

df['check column'] = df.apply(lambda x: check(x, 2005,7), axis = 1)
print(df)  
   year  month                check column
0  2005      7  entry for year month exist
1  2006      9                   not exist
2  2007     12                   not exist
3  2005      7  entry for year month exist
4  2008      9                   not exist
```